# what does a "warning: type defaults to ‘int’" function actually return?

Tags: c, function, types, return, warnings

`foo.c:3:8: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘bar’ [-Wimplicit-int]`

I encountered a warning when trying to compile these two files, which I knew was because I didn't specify the type of bar function at the beginning. But I wanted to figure out what the value returned by the default int return type actually represented. I tried to change the content of the bar function, including the number of parameters and function bodies (such as adding some short statements), but I didn't find any rules for the return value.

foo.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

extern bar();

int main()
{
        int a = 4;
        int ret = bar(a);
        printf("ret = %d\n",ret);
        return 0;
}
```

bar.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void bar(int a)
{
        printf("a = %d\n",a);
}
```

compiled whth `gcc -o fb foo.c bar.c`

and the result

```
a = 4
ret = 6
```

Comment: What you get is undefined behavior.  You failed to define a return type for your function in the prototype leading the program to implicitly assume it has an `int` return type.

Comment: `bar` returns an undefined value. You are using _undefined behavior_. Anything can happen, including a program abort or an infinite loop somewhere (a "hang").

Comment: Have you tried extern void bar(int);?

Comment: You didn't declare the return type for `bar` and the compiler warns that the default type is `int`

Comment: All warnings containing "..,defaults to something..." are actually errors nowadays.

Comment: regarding: `extern bar();`  This is an error.  It should use the same signature as the actual function.  I.E. `extern void bar( int );`

Comment: regarding: `int ret = bar(a);`  This is not a valid statement because the function: `bar()` has the signature return type of `void`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type the function returns and what value the function returns are separate things.

In `extern bar();`, you have not declared the function to return `void`, which would mean nothing is returned. This means it returns something and, due to the history of the C language, the type of what it returns defaults to `int`.

With such a declaration, the function **should** return an `int` value, if its return value is used.

In this code:

```
void bar(int a)
{
        printf("a = %d\n",a);
}
```

you do not return a value. There is no `return` statement. But the return value is used in your `main` routine. The resulting behavior is not defined by the C standard. There are no rules in the C standard for what will happen.